# Downloading files using ASP.NET .ashx modules

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, download, ashx

I have ASP.NET page with an iframe on it for displaying some pdf reports on this page. 
When user select the report type from dropdown, I add the needed for report data into the ASP.NET Session and change the attribute "src" of the iframe to .ashx module address which generates the .pdf report.
But if Adobe glug-in for viewing .pdf files in browser is not installed, browser proposes to save report file and name of the proposed file is "HandlerName.ashx".
But I want to make the browser proposed to save the file with the name "Report.pdf". Can I do this? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Attention. It's need to display generated .pdf file in case Adobe plug-in is installed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try inline content-disposition, however I have to check this:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; 
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + name );
```

Comment: Mike, it's great. Thank you from Kharkov, GlobalLogic. Мир тесен ;)

Comment: :), but as far I know this will not work... А кто ты конкртейней?

Comment: I would play a bit with this solution, but seems that it doesn't work...  "тісніше немає вже куди :D"

Answer (score 7):

Add the following header in your ashx-file:

```
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=PUTYOURFILENAMEHERE.pdf");
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
```

Comment: In this case browser proposes to download file when the Adobe plug-in is installed...

Answer (score 3):

```
Use     


 Response.Clear();
 Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Report.PDF");                                            
 Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/YourPath/Report.PDF"));
 Response.End();
```