# JSon data + file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I need to return textual data from server along with binary data(file) as JSon object which later will be used with jQuery(ASP.NET app at server side). I can encode file with Base64 and put it inside JSon object, as I know there is no way to access binary data using jQuery from JSon object at client side.
So how to call server using jQuery, read textual JSon data and somehow send file at the same request.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you want to do with the returned file client-side?

Comment: I want to show information about file and also send file itself.

Comment: return the information and url pointing to the file on the server instead of file contents.

Comment: I need to use jQuery for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can send information about a file in jQuery request and send to client path to it. And then you can open file with this path with window.open('{File path}').

You can download the file  with Generic handler ashx: [Downloading files using ASP.NET .ashx modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317556/downloading-files-using-asp-net-ashx-modules)

For example:

```
window.open(file.filePath);
```